# Getting my values back as int[,] after storing them in a stack of objects

Tags: c#

I am trying to find a way to get my values back as type int[,] from my stack of type object. I have used this earlier and the solution to getting the values back from a queue was:

```
foreach (int[,] q in replay)
                        {
                            draw.UpdateBoard(q);
                            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
                        }
```

Unfortunalty I cannot use that solution again as I only want to get one of my values from the top of the stack using peek. I need a solution like:

```
Convert.ToInt16(undo.Peek());
```

This would work if there was an option to convert to int[,] instead. I am sure this problem only occurs because of my lack of language knowledge. Or maybe the solution is not as simple as I think it is.

On a side note I have tried instead use a `stack<int[,]>` but then I could not clone my values onto the stack to stop an override issue occurring.

Edit: To clarify, my first problem can be found here: [C# Using A Queue to Store multiple 2D Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47113135/c-sharp-using-a-queue-to-store-multiple-2d-arrays)

Replay is also of type object and the array dimensions are of [8,8].

Comment: Asking about your *first* problem, the one you "fixed" by creating this one, might yield better results.

Comment: What is the type of `replay`?

Comment: So you want to get a multidimentinal array from a stack? What are the array's dimensions?

Comment: Updated my question to answer some questions.

Comment: Do you know what a *cast operator* is in C#?

Comment: No I do not know how to use a cast operator in this instance, I have seen other examples but not ones applying to 1D array of objects to 2D array of integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: a *cast operator* in C# is the operator which says "I know that this expression is actually of this type; throw an exception if I am wrong."  (Note that this is not the *only* meaning of a cast in C#.)

The `as` operator is similar, except it produces `null` rather than an exception if the conversion is unsuccessful. (Note that the `as` operator semantics are not *identical* to cast semantics.)

So you could do:

```
object topObject = undo.Peek();
int[,] topBoard = (int[]) topObject;
```

or

```
int[,] topBoard = topObject as int[,];
```

The slightly longer answer is:  you should never have gotten into this fix in the first place because your queue or stack should have been

```
Queue<int[,]> q = new Queue<int[,]>();
...
q.Enqueue(board.Clone() as int[]);
...
```

or similarly for stacks.

And now dequeueing the board does not require a cast.

The **correct** solution though is to move to an *immutable data structure model for boards*.

Boards should not be an array of integers in the first place. Boards should be an abstract immutable data structure where the array is an implementation detail, and where *a move on a board produces a new board*. Boards never change.  Since boards never change, you can put them in a stack of boards without cloning them.

An alternative solution is that your stack should be two stacks of *undo and redo actions*. If you have stacks of undo and redo actions then you can use a mutable board and run it forwards and backwards in history by applying the actions to it.

The former solution is less bug-prone and easier to reason about.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I appreciate your patience with my what now seems silly question. I encounter a large amount of problems because of my lack keyword knowledge and getting an answer to that solution can be hard to find in a google search. You have helped me to see the problem may not always be as specific as you think it is so researching more broadly could also lead me to my solutions in the future.